# Monaco editor adding dynamic class for addExtraLib

Tags: angular8, intellisense, monaco-editor

I have been trying to use intellisense from monaco editor in my angular application. I needed help in adding auto recommendation to methods for classes that I dynamically have to load.

Eg:I generate classes for different shapes and need to generate method names using intellisense.
Rectangle class will have methods like top, left, right. I generate Rectangle1, Rectangle2....,Ellipse1, Eliipse2, Ellipse3.... and so on for multiple shapes. How to add intellisense so that it recommends left,right,top on generating Rectangle1 class and typing a dot next to it.

```
// validation settings
    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
      noSemanticValidation: true,
      noSyntaxValidation: false
    });

    // compiler options
    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
      target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES6,
      allowNonTsExtensions: true
    });


monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib([

      // Trial code
      'declare class Rectangle1 {',

      '    static ():top',
      '    static ():left',
      '    static ():right',
      '}',
    ].join('\n'));


 var jsCode = [
      '"use strict";',
      '',
      "Rectangle1.top = {",

      " console.log('Rectangle top');",

      "}"
    ].join('\n');


this.editor = monaco.editor.create(this.editorContainer.nativeElement, jsCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code in the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html)

Note that what you pass to `addExtraLib` must be a valid typescript definition.

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: true,
    noSyntaxValidation: false
});

// compiler options
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES6,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true
});

monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib([
    'declare class Rectangle1 {',
    '    /**',
    '     * optional documentation for top function',
    '     */',
    '    static top()',
    '    static left()',
    '    static right()',
    '}'
].join('\n'));

var jsCode = [
    '"use strict";',
    '',
    "Rectangle1.top();"
].join('\n');

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    language: 'javascript',
    value: jsCode
});
```